# Ignore several warnings in Android lint

Tags: android, android-resources, lint

I know I can ignore a rule in Lint with attribute `tools:ignore`

My difficulty is that I want to ignore several rules.
In my case, for Google analytics `ga_trackingId`, I want to ignore *TypographyDashes* and *MissingTranslation*

I tried with no success

```
<resources tools:ignore="TypographyDashes|MissingTranslation" xmlns:tools="https://schemas.android.com/tools" >
```

and

```
<resources tools:ignore="TypographyDashes,MissingTranslation" xmlns:tools="https://schemas.android.com/tools" >
```

and

```
<resources tools:ignore="TypographyDashes MissingTranslation" xmlns:tools="https://schemas.android.com/tools" >
```

I am now out of ideas. How can I specify several values in `tools:ignore`?

Comment: According to documentation comma separated list should do this. See bottom of this developer page; http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/improving-w-lint.html

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @harism. I have opened [issue 43070](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=43070)

Comment: @harism Good catch on the namespace; I'd like to credit you with the accepted answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem here was usage of wrong namespace uri in xml resource file;

```
xmlns:tools="https://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Which should have been `http://...` protocol instead. This is discussed in more details in [issue 43070](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=43070)

Comment: In a word: don't follow the documentation and use the 'http' namespace instead :)

Answer (score 50):

You need to use a comma separated list, but there must not be blanks.

Example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" // required to work
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="contentDescription,SpUsage" > // comma separated list. NO blanks allowed!
```

For a list of the valid options you can get a list from the command line or use the eclipse lint error checking list mentioned by throrin19:

```
lint --list > lint_options.txt
```

See [lint documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/lint.html#config_keywords).

Comment: This is exactly what I'm finding. :)

Answer (score 2):

Used you eclipse or intelliJ ?

In Eclipse, go to Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Lint Error Checking

[image]

And have a fun ;-)

Comment: It helps, but this configuration doesn't have the same scope.

Comment: This image was used to illustrate just where you were going to happen.

Answer (score 2):

You can put multiple annotations on specific strings to ignore multiple lint checks:

*strings.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>    

    <!--suppress MissingTranslation -->
    <!--suppress TypographyDashes -->
    <string name="some_string">ignore my translation</string>
    ...

</resources>
```

http://tools.android.com/tips/lint/suppressing-lint-warnings

Comment: The site is disabled.